# $.ajax function parameters are not defined

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using ajax function to send date value to a method in controller but ajax function is not hitting method and getting an success function call in ajax.

When debugging this function in console I am getting 'url is not defined','type is not defined'.

[image: type is not defined]
[image: url is not defined]

Ajax Function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker(
            {
                todayHighlight: true,
                autoclose: true,
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: "-50:+50",
                showOption: { origin: ["bottom", "left"] },
                maxDate: new Date(),
                altField: "#input_date",
                onSelect: function () {

                    var ScheduleDate = $('#input_date').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: '@Url.Action("getTeamAndVenueDetails", "IPL")',                            
                        data: { ScheduleDate: ScheduleDate },
                        success: function (result) {
                            console.log(result);
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            console.log(xhr.status);
                            console.log(xhr.responseText);
                            console.log(thrownError);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
    });
```

Method in Controller:

```
 public JsonResult getTeamAndVenueDetails(DateTime ScheduleDate)
        {
            List<Maalaimalar.Contracts.Sports.TeamAndVenue> TeamAndVenueDetails = new List<Maalaimalar.Contracts.Sports.TeamAndVenue>();
            TeamAndVenueDetails = _provider.GetTeamAndVenueDetail(ScheduleDate);
            return Json("test", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: I don't think it's an issue to be honest. I've seen it before, where Chrome is trying to scope the variable to be helpful. It's not a variable, but rather an object property. Have a look at the network request instead. That will tell you more useful info.

Comment: I watched the XHR result in chrome.The url send from ajax call is "http://localhost:61478/IPL/getTeamAndVenueDetails?ScheduleDate=02%2F03%2F2018".But it is not hitting the function.It is calling the Error Layout.

Comment: What is the error response? 404, 500?

Comment: Status is 200.But it is returning default error page "http://localhost:61478/Error/NotFound"

Comment: Is it being redirected to that page? Might be worth putting some breakpoints on your middleware.

Comment: is there any need to define routing for ajax call ?